# Would we be interested in holding a question drive (contest)?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In the distant past we [talked about having a question drive](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/408/1993) and later [held a genre Q&A contest](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/757/1993), but that was all years ago.  I recently saw an [answerathon](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4865/472) contest on another site, and that got me thinking about similar ideas for our site.

We, unlike Mi Yodeya, don't have a lot of old unanswered questions; in fact, currently the unanswered tab shows only [11 questions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/unanswered).  We're doing fine on *answers*; we have a community full of people who are ready to provide answers.  What we need is *more (good-quality) questions*.

Would people be interested in holding some sort of contest aimed at encouraging more of the kinds of questions we want?  I'm imagining something like: you get one point for each qualifying question over some period of time, competing for glory and the chance to make Writing even better than it already is and whatever prizes I come up with.  "Qualifying" would probably mean some minimum score and not closed and whatever other criteria we think are important.

Thoughts?  Would people be interested in a little friendly competitive site-growth?

Comment: It might help our questions-per-week.

Comment: I think maybe not just "questions", but maybe use this opportunity to add more questions to certain tags? For example, tags that have less than 200 questions? It could help us not only have more content, but more varied content.

Comment: Something like Worldbuilding's [fortnightly topic challenges](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1768/29), you mean?

Comment: @aCVn I'd been thinking of a single event (like the contest we had a long time ago), but if we can get interest in a recurring challenge that'd be great too.  I left this vague so that people could react and help refine it. :-)

Comment: Just thought I'd mention: today our Area 51 page showed 7 question/day. See printscreen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcJTF.png A question drive NOW might just give us the push to finally go over 10 questions/day.

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea of boosting questions, so long as they're good questions.  Or at least interesting.

We have 22 tags which have been used in at least 200 questions.

Another 20 tags have been used in 100-199 questions.

If we get to where we have 40 tags used in at least 200 questions, our site will allow people to earn the Generalist badge (15 net upvotes in each of 20 tags that are in the top 40 tags).

Any tag that is used in at least 100 questions can be used to earn a tag badge (for bronze tag badges, it's 100 net upvotes total for answers to at least 20 questions).

Let's have a question-a-thon that focuses on tags with fewer than 200 uses.  (Or a focus on those < 100 uses or those in the 100-199 range.)